# Window Phone: Implementing list search similar to People Hub, Email Search, Call history

Tags: c#, .net, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-7.1

I have tried the auto complete box component from the Windows Phone toolkit, but I know it isn't half as fast or smooth as the people hub search, email search or the call history search; is there a way to implement the same list search mechanism employed within these standard Windows Phone apps / modules? or is this a control custom developed by Microsoft that isn't available to the general public?

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend that you evaluate Telerik's Windows Phone controls.

http://www.telerik.com/products/windows-phone/overview/all-controls.aspx

I've used a number of the controls in my WP7 apps, and their support is second to none!